# Some Laravel Anonymous Component Props always use default values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have an anonymous component `layout.blade.php` that has the following props and how they are used, some meta tags have been removed for brevity:

```php
@props([
    'meta' => [
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'description' => 'Some description',
        'url' => 'https://somesite.com',
        'image' => 'images/banner.png', 
    ],
    'robots' => 'index, follow',
    'keywords' => 'some, comma, separated, keywords'
])

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="{{ $meta['description'] }}">
        <meta name="robots" content="{{ $robots }}" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="{{ $keywords }}" />

        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="{{ $meta['title'] }}"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="{{ $meta['description'] }}" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="{{ $meta['url'] }}" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{asset($meta['image'])}}" />

        <meta property="twitter:title" content="{{ $meta['title'] }}" />
        <meta property="twitter:description" content="{{ $meta['description'] }}" />

        <link rel="canonical" href="{{ $meta['url'] }}"/>
        <title>{{ $meta['title'] }}</title>
    </head>
```

Whenever I pass data via a controller e.g.:

```php
return(view('plans.index', [
    'plans' => auth()->user()->plans()->get(),
    'robots' => 'noindex'
]));
```

The `meta` prop will always resolve to the correct values passed, whether that is default or something I provide.

In the case of `robots` and `keywords` they always are the defaults provided. I can't find any documentation that explains this behaviour and can't see where I am going wrong.

EDIT:
An example of how the layout is being called is below:

```php
<x-layout>
    @section('content')
    <section class="w-full bg-white">
        @include('partials.hero')
    </section>
    <section id="features" class="py-24 bg-blue-500">
        @include('partials.explainer')
    </section>
    <section id="waitlist" class="py-24 bg-white">
        @include('partials.form')
    </section>
    @endsection
</x-layout>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call to layout? you might not passing the parameters correctly

Comment: Added an example to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, You should **PASS** the variables you want to the anonymous component, so you should call your layout component as so:

```
<x-layout :robots="$robots" :keywords="$keywords">
```

[data-properties-attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#data-properties-attributes)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make it conditional so if that variable is not passed to the view then it won't fail? Why does the $meta tag work exactly as intended?

Comment: You should use the `@props` directive as you use in your question, it can have a default values but it can be overwriten if you pass other values. about the meta variable, I can't examine it without see your all code, you might register it as global variable in one of your service providers or you are doing something different, You can try what I suggested and open a new question for the meta variable beahvior

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think it would be better for me to use a class based component as that can handle optional attributes better.